# How to ensure that data connected to external source has been refreshed

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an excel file which acts as a daily reporting tool and accesses data from an Access database. I have selected the option of refreshing data when workbook opens for all connections. However, today in the morning, when I opened the workbook, only a part of the data got refreshed. I suspect that it might be due to the fact that I was using wireless internet. A second attempt at refreshing the data was successful so there is nothing wrong with the data sources

So my question: is it possible to receive some sort of a confirmation when all the data has been refreshed? I thought about making a query in Access which returns today's date and then connecting this query to a cell in Excel. However, this does not solve the problem because this query result might get updated but the others might not

Comment: it is possible to retrieve data with `QueryTable object` and us its event to find out if data are retrieved. [Here some more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff835922(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: thanks for your reply...in my case the external data is a) either directly entered into certain cells or b) acts as source for pivot tables

do you have any suggestions for these two cases?

Comment: what does it mean `directly entered into certain cells`?? behind `PivotTables` there is `PivotCache` behind which a kind of `Connection` to external data is set. You need to explain your situation with more details.

Comment: Well I retrieve external data (from Microsoft Query in my case) and then I point to a cell location where I want to place my data. This is for case 'a' that I mentioned above. Case 'b' involves pivot tables

Comment: Case A can be rather converted into `QueryTable` solution.

Comment: alright thanks...and for pivot tables?

Comment: use ADO DB for PivotTables (as a source for PivotCache)